# Erlang: Implementing a Finite State Machine using gen_fsm

Tags: erlang, gen-fsm

I'm looking for an example of a simple FSM implemented in Erlang using the gen_fsm from OTP.

Answer (score 8):

I found this tutorial really helpful -

http://spawnlink.com/articles/an-introduction-to-gen_fsm-erlybanks-atm/index.html

Answer (score 5):

You can also refer to the official erlang documentation.

http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/fsm.html

The locked door example reported in the link is quite easy to understand